# Diferencia de fecha actual entre PHP y Base de Datos

Tags: php, mysql, date

Tengo en mi base de datos (mysql) que trabajo con xampp, un campo Facha de Registro que se alimenta automáticamente con un **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**. Con PHP consulto la fecha y hora actual con la sentencia **date("Y-m-d H:i:s")**.

Todo ello con la finalidad de mostrar el tiempo que ha pasado desde el registro realizado. El problema esta, en que **date("Y-m-d H:i:s")** me esta entregando una fecha muy superior a la actual, con diferencia en horas.

¿Alguien sabrá porque ocurre esto? o ¿estoy usando mal date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ?

Answer (score 0):

probablemente php no esté usando tu zona horaria, y tenga otra por defecto. A esto lo resuelves de dos formas:

La primera, es poner tu zona horaria correcta en el php.ini, modificando el valor date.timezone = tuzona/horaria , por ejemplo la mía es: date.timezone= America/Montevideo .
Puedes ver que zona horaria tiene definida PHP en el infophp.php. O con la función date_default_timezone_get() que retorna un string con la zona horaria por defecto, si es que hay una definida.

La segunda forma es decirle a php que use tu zona horaria temporalmente así:

```
<?php
// la zona horaria por defecto en el php.ini
echo date_default_timezone_get ();
echo "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

// fijar tu zona horaria "momentaneamente"
date_default_timezone_set("America/Montevideo");
echo "America/Montevideo:";//.time();
echo "<br>";

// tu fecha y hora correctas
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, actualmente he hecho lo siguiente: $ahora = $link->query("SELECT NOW() AS fecha")->fetch_assoc()['fecha']; Me pregunto porque php y mysql estarán retornando en zonas horarias diferentes. Será que cada uno tiene configuraciones distintas ?